# I have a Blazor Server side project and want to populate dropdown list with a json file

Tags: .net, blazor, blazor-server-side

I want to populate dropdown list in my Blazor Server side (.NET8) application.

I have this json file:
filteroptions.json

```
{
  "Name": [ "Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name4"],
  "Occupation": [ "Occupation1", "Occupation2" ],
  "Age": [ "20-29", "30-39", "40-49", "50-59"]
}
```

In program.cs I wonder what I can type to use this json file in multiple pages. I had a blazor WASM before and I could do that with this code in program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton(async x =>
{
    var httpClient = x.GetRequiredService<HttpClient>();
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress);
    return await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<FilterOptionsResponseDto>("filteroptions.json")
        .ConfigureAwait(false);
});
```

But when I migrated to Blazor Server Side,

```
builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress
```

doesnt work because "WebApplicationBuilder doesnt not contain a definition for 'HostEnvironment'..."

Instead, locally, I did this (which works locally):

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton(async x =>
{
    var httpClient = x.GetRequiredService<HttpClient>();
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44338/");

    return await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<FilterOptionsResponseDto>("filteroptions.json");

});
```

But when publishing the application, this doesnt work. Target machine is actively refusing it.

Any ideas how I can use my filteroptions.json in multiple pages by adding it as singleton in my program.cs?

Comment: So you are publishing the app with localhost as the target address for your config?

Comment: its the default value in my config

Comment: And you are testing the published app locally?

Answer (score 0):

Inject the `NAvigationManager` with the HttpClient.

I usually use a scoped or transient version of this:

```cs
public class ApiService
{
    public ApiService(HttpClient httpClient, NavigationManager navigationManager)
    {
        HttpClient = httpClient;
        NavigationManager = navigationManager;
        HttpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(NavigationManager.BaseUri);
    }

    public HttpClient HttpClient { get; }
    public NavigationManager NavigationManager { get; }
}
```

Comment: Do I inject it inside my Api Service or program.cs?

Answer (score 0):

There's now the `IHttpClientFactory`.

You can add a named service like this.  It grabs the data it needs when an instance is actually created.

```cs
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("ServerAPI", (s, client) => 
{
    var navManager = s.GetRequiredService<NavigationManager>();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(navManager.BaseUri);
});
```

And then use it like this:

```cs
public class APIWeatherForecastProvider : IWeatherForecastProvider
{
    private IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;
    private List<WeatherForecast>? _forecasts;

    public APIWeatherForecastProvider(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
    }

    public async Task<ListResult<WeatherForecast>> GetWeatherForecastsAsync(ListRequest request, CancellationToken? cancellationToken = null)
    {
        using var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("ServerAPI");

        var httpResult = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync<ListRequest>("/API/Weather/GetWeatherForecasts", request, cancellationToken ?? new());

        if (httpResult.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var listResult = await httpResult.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<ListResult<WeatherForecast>>();
            return listResult;
        }
        return ListResult<WeatherForecast>.Failure($"Request failed.  Error Code: {httpResult.StatusCode.ToString()}");
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I use this in my situation?

Comment: So I can implement it in program.cs without creating a service. I have the json file under wwwroot and want to use it in multiple pages